# Powershell v5 - variable name replacement when referring to WPF objects

Tags: powershell, variables, wpf-controls

I have 5 buttons which will fire file selection dialog to populate 5 text fields with the selected file-path.  One button per file selection to fill a single WPF form text field.
I don't want to do this with a switch statement by repeating 6 lines of code for each button.  I want to simplify it.
I can get the sender button name but what I cant do is set the text field using a variable set through the switch option.  Any ideas?

## General buttons file selection handler

$WPFselectmergefile1.AddHandler([System.Windows.Controls.Button]::ClickEvent, $selectmergefile)
$WPFselectmergefile2.AddHandler([System.Windows.Controls.Button]::ClickEvent, $selectmergefile)

...

```
# handler function - as is - so this one works with lines per option.
[System.Windows.RoutedEventHandler]$Script:SelectMergeFile = {
param($sender, $e)
switch($sender.name) {
'selectmergefile1'  {
    FileDetails 'mergefile1' $WPFmergefile1.Text 2 # prep store 
    $x = File $Global:SourceFolder
    $WPFmergefile1.Text = $x
    $Global:SelectedMergeFile1 = $x
    FileDetails 'mergefile1' $WPFmergefile1.Text 2 # update store
 }
 'selectmergefile2' {
    FileDetails 'mergefile2' $WPFmergefile2.Text 2 
    $x = File $Global:SourceFolder
    $WPFmergefile2.Text = $x
    $Global:SelectedMergeFile2 = $x 
    FileDetails 'mergefile2' $WPFmergefile2.Text 2
 }
...

# What I want to do:
[System.Windows.RoutedEventHandler]$Script:SelectMergeFile = {
    param($sender, $e)
    $opt = $sender.Substring($sender.length-1)
    FileDetails "mergefile$opt" $WPFmergefile$opt.Text 2 
    $x = File $Global:SourceFolder
    $WPFmergefile$opt.Text = $x
    $Global:SelectedMergeFile$opt = $x  
    FileDetails "mergefile$opt" $WPFmergefile$opt.Text 2
}
```

I have tried for variable substitution:

```
"mergefile$opt"        # which works

$WPFmergefile$opt.Text    # which doesnt
$WPFmergefile$($opt).Text # which doesnt
$Global:SelectedMergeFile$opt = .. # which doesnt
```

Not sure what I need to do here..

Comment: `(Get-Variable "mergefile$opt" -ValueOnly).Text`

Comment: Thanks! I also tried variations on that but not that specific one.  With my edited text above, what works is to use exactly that but with the right field name.  so the final edit was: `(get-variable "WPFmergefile$opt" -valueOnly).Text = $x`

Comment: [ANSWERED] I am not sure how to mark this comment from @Mathias as the answer.  But it is.

Comment: [ANSWERED 2] I also spend a bit more time looking at the Global variable issue.  I can resolve that by using the following: `Set-Variable -Name "SelectedMergeFile2$opt" -Value $x -Scope Global`

Answer (score 1):

As suggested in the comments, you can use `Get-Variable -ValueOnly` to retrieve the value of a variable by name:

```
(Get-Variable "mergefile$opt" -ValueOnly).Text
```

---

That being said, you might want to consider organizing your controls in a hashtable or other dictionary type instead.

Assuming you have something like the folowing in place to automatically assign XAML controls to variables:

```
$xaml.SelectNodes("//*[@Name]") | ForEach-Object {
    Set-Variable -Name "WPF$($_.Name)" -Value $Window.FindName($_.Name)
}
```

Replace it with:

```
# create hashtable to hold the control references
$WPFControls = @{}

$xaml.SelectNodes("//*[@Name]") | ForEach-Object {
    $WPFControls[$_.Name] = $Window.FindName($_.Name)
}
```

Now you can easily reference the controls by name:

```
$WPFControls["mergefile$opt"].Text = $x
```